# WPF C# Insert image inside textblock in a specific place (code)

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock

I want to add an image inside a Textblock in a specific place during execution. I am doing a chat for a game and these images will be emoticons. I want to make a method which puts the image at the end of the sentence, but the one that I have made does not work well because the emoticon always appears at the end of the sentence.

The chat should look like this:

Player 1: Hi *(Image)

Player 2: I do not want to talk with you *2(Image2)

But the my chat looks like this:

Player 1: Hi *

Player: I do not want to talk with you *2 (Image)(Image2)

The code:

```
        foreach(char CharOfTheEmoticon in MiChatBox.Text)
        {

            if (CharOfTheEmoticon.Equals('*'))
            {
            BitmapImage MyImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"..\..\..\..\Tarea6\Tarea3Frontend\NewImages\Smile.png", UriKind.Relative));
            Image image = new Image();
            image.Source = MyImageSource;
            image.Width = 15;
            image.Height = 15;
            image.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            InlineUIContainer container = new InlineUIContainer(image);
            Run run = new Run();
            run.Text = "*";
            MiChatBox.Inlines.Add(container);
            MiChatBox.Inlines.Add(run);
            }

         //More if for a differents images
        }
```

The position of the image is indicated by a specific char (for example * o *2)
 I want to use a normal TextBlock   not a RichTextBlock
 I think that this is possible with a normal TextBlock because it can be done in the xaml.
 Thanks for your attention and hopefully you can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"MiChatBox.Inlines.Add" It adds at the end of all.
That way you should do:

```
 var strBuild = new StringBuilder();
 var input = MiChatBox.Text;
 MiChatBox.Text = "";

 foreach (char CharOfTheEmoticon in input)
 {
     strBuild.Append(CharOfTheEmoticon);

     if (CharOfTheEmoticon == '*')
     {

         BitmapImage MyImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"..\..\..\..\Tarea6\Tarea3Frontend\NewImages\Smile.png", UriKind.Relative));
         Image image = new Image();

         image.Source = MyImageSource;
         image.Width = 15;
         image.Height = 15;
         image.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
         InlineUIContainer container = new InlineUIContainer(image);

         var originLastrText = new Run(strBuild.ToString());
         MiChatBox.Inlines.Add(originLastrText);
         MiChatBox.Inlines.Add(container);

         strBuild.Clear();
     }
 }

 var textRem = new Run(strBuild.ToString());
 MiChatBox.Inlines.Add(textRem);
```

Comment: Better not use StringBuilder, but [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7cct0x33(v=vs.110).aspx).
But I had no power to the demo.